# Java vs. C++ - Raytracing

Tags: java, c++, performance, raytracing

I created simple ray tracer in Java as a hobby project, and well, it's slow. Not dramatically slow, but slow nevertheless. I wonder if I can get any performance gain using lower level language like C or C++ or will the difference be negligible and I should stick to improving "my" algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question have been answered as YES a not interpreted language will in 99.99% of the cases run faster than the same algorithm under a VM.
This said (having worked a lot in image processing both in java and c/c++ where memory and time mattered) I think you should at first try to optimize your code, here are are my advises:

- Try to find the bottleneck of your code using a profiler. A lot of things we sometimes omit can be reveled with such tools (like type casting, unnecessary creation of objects, most critical functions which should be optimized at first) A profiler have to be your friend.

Then (just few examples I could see for raytracing):

- Replace tan/sin/cos by lookup tables (as long as you can) or [approximate functions](http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/07/18/fast-and-accurate-sinecosine-approximation/)
- Try to process data per array and not per sample
- Try using multiple threads
- …

Now those things are "good" but if the speed is really critical for you, I would not suggest to use a c or c++ language (even if you could) but more likely to focus on OpenCL. This is probably the best tool available and most adapted for building ray tracings engine. Just imagine you are not talking there of an improvement of 30% but more likely 10'000% (100x faster) Here is a java interface: http://jogamp.org/jocl/www/
Good luck :-)

Comment: If you can generally notice the difference between a JITed code and code generated by a c++ compiler you're either using compiler intrinsics to do stuff neither compiler could, measure situations where the language spec forces the one language to be slower or got the measurements wrong. And getting the latter wrong is extremely simple (or other said: it's extremely hard to do correctly). Anyways: Going with a GPU solution for raytracing is obviously superior and using lookup tables on modern CPUs may not be such a great idea ;-)

Comment: Mmmm I do not get the last point: optimization is most of the time (not to say always) a memory vs cpu tradeoff. Lookup tables is only one among others: this is just a kind of manual cache (and you sure know how cache is important to get something running smoothly ;-) )

Comment: Depends. The memory vs. cpu tradeoff is well known, but in this case computing the sin anew may be faster than looking it up in the table - especially if you've got lots of computation going on. The table also evicts some other useful data from the cache or may be evicted itself (not good for performance either). So that's something one has to benchmark to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend. Using C/C++ will allow you access to things that you can't do in Java. (such as SIMD)

In other words, I'd say yes, it's *usually* possible do better in C/C++, but it will take some work. Do all your basic (mathematical/algorithmic) optimizations first. Then micro-optimize later.

Comment: "such as SIMD" - modern JITs already vectorize code, so if he isn't going to use compiler intrinsics the difference will probably be pretty small.

Comment: @Voo: Hence why I said "but it will take some work". And SIMD is just one example among others.

Comment: It probably can't do it as well as human as it have to guess what to parallel. Well, if was using SIMD I would probably use OpenCL instead of CPU instructions.

Comment: Not only have you access to SIMD in C++, but could you e.g. write a 8byte-node kd-tree implementation in Java?

Answer (score 3):

AMD just released an open source project called Aparapi which converts Java bytecode to OpenCL at runtime.  If your code can't be converted to OpenCL (there are restrictions) or if you don't have OpenCL available the code will run in a Thread Pool.

Might be ideal for your needs.

http://aparapi.googlecode.com

Comment: That's impressive if it works well, +1 for an interesting find *and* a useful summary in the answer you posted to go with and complement the link

Answer (score 2):

As you only know the details behind your implementation this is hard to answer. If your approach is mostly mathematical then Java has all kinds of optimizations going on behind the scenes here and I don't think you will see much in the way of improvements by switching to C++.

If you are using a lot of external libraries, and depending on your method of displaying the raytraced result to screen there may be improvements moving to a C-based implementation.

Comment: I don't use any external libraries, and displaying the result is actually pretty quick. It's producing the result what takes most of a time. I can include a screen from VisualVM if it will be any help...

Comment: There are lots of math libraries in C/C++, too.

Answer (score 2):

Switching to C/C++ will give you marginal gains if you are using inefficient algorithms in addition to a whole cartload of headaches learning the new language. Properly written Java can achieve roughly 70-80% speed of similar C/C++ code and should be good enough for a non-commercial ray-tracer. I assume the ray-tracer is now functionally complete so my recommendation would be to learn how to use profilers to detect bottle-necks in your code. Remember the 80/20 rule (or is 90/10, 75/25 or so?) where your program spends 80% percent of its time running 20% of its code.

Better algorithms usually give better performance boosts than language switches.

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency on ray tracing relies on your acceleration structure. Using C++ instead of Java would certainly helps. However, if you lack of an efficient structure such as BVH or Kd-tree, your ray tracer will be slow in any language you use.

If it is just a hobby, I suggest to stay on Java. If you want to load complex models such as Stanford Buddha or Thai, then you definitely should move to C++ and start reading "Physically Based Rendering": http://www.pbrt.org/ You can download the Chapter 4 for free at http://pbrt.org/pbrt-2ed-chap4.pdf

In few words, you can answer your question based on the objectives of your project. Simple hobby=stay on Java. Real-time RT with complex models=C++

Answer (score 1):

I've done a simple raytracer in Java a few years ago. For pretty simple mesh (the famous teapot 3D mesh and the rabbit 3D mesh) I could do the computation with a real time rendering. So I guess you can do it too =)

If it's hobby, stick with Java, it's not worth it moving to C++. And instead of changing the language, think where you can improve your code (finding the triangle that is hit by the ray in log(n) time, multithreaded programming, etc...)

Comment: BSP? What resolution? With or without anti-aliasing? And what hardware where you using (so I can have comparison).

Comment: Yeah, BSP, with necessarily a good resolution, the mesh was pretty small (69,451 triangles for the stanford bunny), no antialiasing, but I'm pretty sure we did a simple phong reflection model (the teapot looked round, not with edges). The computer spec is unknown, but you can guess, it was three years ago, on a public campus computer (probably a E6200 with no graphics card)

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you will see a significant performance gain with c or c++.  You can try converting your code using a tool like [this](http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Java_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html).

Comment: I don't see how simple translation of code can give any significant improvement.

Comment: Because compiling C or C++ with optimizations may produce much faster machine code than HotSpot will - but that's a big MAYBE.  There are a bunch of factors that can improve or degrade performance of both languages.